# Android emulator with Moto360 like insets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, wear-os

Is there a way to run the Android Emulator with a Moto360-like display configuration in order to test the GUI layout? There is the round screen layout, but I don't see any way to specify the 30-pixel window inset at the bottom.